# How to use d'Alembert principle in rotating and translating objects

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, momentum

Imagine we have this situation:

[image]

We want to know the $\theta$ in the equilibrium. However since there is not a fixed point around which everything turn around I don't really know how to find the generalised forces to use the D'Alembert principle.

Comment: Just use some trig to compute the height of P as a function of $\theta$. It will have a mximum which is an unstable equilibrium position.